# I am trying to load a Sequence of dates for each and every id in a SQL table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with some id's, I would like to link sequence of dates to those id's,
Sample Table:

```
  ID
12345
54321
78945
32165
```

I am trying to get result like this:

```
 ID       Dates
12345  01/01/2017
54321  01/01/2017
78945  01/01/2017
32165  01/01/2017

12345  01/02/2017
54321  01/02/2017
78945  01/02/2017
32165  01/02/2017

12345  01/03/2017
54321  01/03/2017
78945  01/03/2017
32165  01/03/2017
```

or

```
  ID      Dates
12345  01/01/2017
12345  01/02/2017
12345  01/03/2017
12345  01/04/2017

54321  01/01/2017
54321  01/02/2017
54321  01/03/2017
54321  01/04/2017


78945  01/01/2017
78945  01/02/2017
78945  01/03/2017
78945  01/04/2017
```

Can someone assist on this.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use an ad-hoc tally table to create date desired date range and then a simple CROSS JOIN with your data

```
declare @from date = '2009-01-01'
declare @to date   = '2017-01-21'

Select ID,
      ,Dates = D
 From (
       Select Top (DateDiff(DD,@from,@to)+1) D=DateAdd(DD,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null))-1,@from) 
       From master..spt_values N1 ,master..spt_values N2 
      ) A
 Cross Join YourTable
```

Comment: Interesting approach with the "built-in", yet undocumented `spt_values` table! Works like a charm, but unfortunately only up to 2048 records. Unfortunately tere are 2942 days between the given dates.

Comment: Ahh, OK, got it: You cross-linked the `spt_values` tables twice, thereby giving you a scope of 2048*2048 records!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select id, dt
from data
  cross join ( 
      values ('2017-01-01'), ('2017-02-01'), ('2017-03-01') 
   ) t (dt)
order by dt, id;
```

If you use `order by id,dt` you get the second result.

Comment: Thanks, What if I want to add all the dates between '01-01-2009' and '01-21-2017' to the id's

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with a AS (
  select cast('2009-1-1' AS datetime) dt
  union all
  select dateadd(day,1,dt) from a where dt<'2017-1-21'
)
select id, dt from a 
cross join data
order by id, dt -- or: dt, id 
option ( maxrecursion 3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using master.dbo.spt_values

```
;WITH yourtable(ID)AS(
   SELECT 12345 UNION
   SELECT 54321 UNION
   SELECT 78945 UNION
   SELECT 32165
 )
 SELECT ID,CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(d,sv.number,c.StartDay)) 
 FROM yourtable AS t,master.dbo.spt_values AS sv
 CROSS APPLY(VALUES('01/01/2017',10)) c(StartDay,DayCount)  --Parameter of initial
 WHERE sv.type='P' AND sv.number BETWEEN 0 AND c.DayCount-1
```

output：

```
ID          
----------- ----------
12345       2017-01-01
12345       2017-01-02
12345       2017-01-03
12345       2017-01-04
12345       2017-01-05
12345       2017-01-06
12345       2017-01-07
12345       2017-01-08
12345       2017-01-09
12345       2017-01-10
32165       2017-01-01
32165       2017-01-02
32165       2017-01-03
32165       2017-01-04
32165       2017-01-05
32165       2017-01-06
32165       2017-01-07
32165       2017-01-08
32165       2017-01-09
32165       2017-01-10
54321       2017-01-01
54321       2017-01-02
54321       2017-01-03
54321       2017-01-04
54321       2017-01-05
54321       2017-01-06
54321       2017-01-07
54321       2017-01-08
54321       2017-01-09
54321       2017-01-10
78945       2017-01-01
78945       2017-01-02
78945       2017-01-03
78945       2017-01-04
78945       2017-01-05
78945       2017-01-06
78945       2017-01-07
78945       2017-01-08
78945       2017-01-09
78945       2017-01-10
```